# Sketch the set of points determined by the following condition

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

$|2 \overline{z}+i|=4$

if I let $z=x+yi$, I got $4x^2+(1-2y)^2=16$

I don't know if that's right. Should I just plot that in wolfram alpha?

Comment: Equation looks good to me, it is an circle

Comment: Oh an ellipse, I didn't think of that. How did you simplify it?

Comment: Remove brackets, divide by 4 and get in standard form: $x^2+(y-0.5)^2=4$, a circle

Comment: No you should not since $|2 \overline{z}+i|=4 \implies |2| | \overline{z} + \frac{i}{2}| = 4 \implies  |z - \frac{i}{2}| = 2$, it is obvious a circle. Or from your conclusion, $4x^2+(1-2y)^2=16 \implies x^2+(y-1/2)^2= 4$

Comment: That is indeed quicker, provided one sees the conjugate trick...I followed the OP's path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quick way to sketch that graph without an electronic grapher, as when taking a test.

Divide both sides of your equation by two and change the addition to a subtraction, and you get

$$\left|\overline{z}-\left(-\frac i2\right)\right|=2$$

The modulus of the difference of two complex numbers is the distance between the two numbers (points) in the complex plane. So this says that the distance between $\overline z$ and $-\frac i2$ is $2$. We change this to a statement about $z$ by now flipping the complex plane about the real axis, replacing each number with its conjugate. I.e. now we have the distance between $z$ and $\frac i2$ is $2$. (Another way to get that is to take the conjugates of both sides of the equation, which is easily done.)

This is a circle with radius $2$ and the center $\frac i2$.

Comment: I indeed like this way better.